# Exporting Custom Menu Translation

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n, configuration

Question: **How do I export/import translation of Custom Menu Items**

I have a module that takes all the .po files for custom strings and then uses locale to batch import them. This works great.

I was wanting to translate my custom menu links, but when I search for them in the translate interface (or searching the .po from exporting my translations) I am unable to find any of the menu items.

I've included my admin/config/regional/content-language settings below so you can see that Custom Menu Link (and it's menu link title) is ticked.

I **am** able to translate the menu items only by going to `admin/structure/menu/item/#/edit/translations`, but this isn't (seemingly) exportable in either the .po files (via locale export), nor the config management system (via drush cex).

Anyone know how to do this? Thanks in advance.

[image: admin/config/regional/content-language settings]

Answer (score 0):

So what I ended up doing was to create a module that reads from a json file, and adds the translation. (Import controller + drush command)

a) Load up the custom menu items by menu name:

```
$main_menu_items = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('menu_link_content')->loadByProperties(array('menu_name' => $menu_name));
```

b) Go through your menu items, foreach of them check if your menu link title matches one in your json/po file/config.

c) Check if you already have a translation on that menu item, then remove the old translation or skip.

```
if ($menu_item->hasTranslation('fr')) {
```

d) Finally add the translation that exists in your file.

```
  $menu_item_fr = $menu_item->addTranslation('fr');
  $menu_item_fr->title = $translation_json[$menu_name][$link_title];
  $menu_item_fr->description = '';
  $menu_item_fr->save();
```

This is essentially what my json looked like:

```
{"menu_name": {"english_link_title":"french_link_title"}}
```

Do hope this helps someone else, or someone can think up a better answer.